# MySQL + Sequelize: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, foreign-keys, sequelize.js

Im trying to insert a row in my tweets table that has a foreignKey referenced to the userID in the User table, because a tweet has a user.

This is my sql query that is automatically generated my sequelize:

```
INSERT INTO `tweets`

(`id`,`timestamp`,`content`,`postedImageURL`,`userID`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?);
```

i get this Error:

> (conn=457, no: 1452, SQLState: 23000) Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`twitter`.`tweets`, CONSTRAINT `tweets_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userID`) REFERENCES `users` (`userID`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE)

In the users model i defined the foreign key this way:

```
DBUser.hasMany(DBTweet, { foreignKey: 'userID' })
```

Here are my two tables:

[tweets Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwqBP.png)

[users table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tKg8.png)

Comment: I believe the SQL is OK.  But, what value are you passing to the `tweets.userId`?  This needs to an existing user (i.e. who is tweeting?)

Comment: yea that was my issue. Fixed it now